# CSS Flexbox: Keep two items in same column

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to achieve the following with HTML + CSS, ideally using flex:

```
item 1    item 2    item 4    item 5
**        **        **        **
**                  **        **
**        item 3    **        **
**        **        **        **

item 6    item 7
**        **
**        **
**        **
**        **
```

The idea is to allow a content editor to add items to a queue, and for each item they can decide if it should be a "half" or "full" card.

Every item should be in a separate flex column, except every two items marked as "half" should be in the same column.

Ideally, the "half" items should have exactly 1/2 row height, minus gap.

Or rather: Items which are marked as "half" should be grouped into the same column.

On mobile / narrow viewport, the layout would shrink to 3 columns, 2 columns, 1 column.

I know I could achieve this by wrapping item 2 + item 3 into a container.

But can I achieve it with a "flat" html structure, like this?

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>item 1</div>
  <div class="half first">item 2</div>
  <div class="half second">item 3</div>
  <div>item 4</div>
  <div>item 5</div>
  <div>item 6</div>
  <div>item 7</div>
</div>
```

I assume I can give the items classes like "half first" and "half second". But I cannot give them unique ids that I would target with CSS, because we don't know how many items an editor might create.

So far I am looking at flex. But if CSS grid works, why not.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with flex without altering the markup. You could do it with grid by leveraging grid-row/grid-column rules.

Comment: I tried something with grid, but the "full" column following the two "half" columns was shifted down.. https://jsfiddle.net/orxkajw0/ or check this version https://jsfiddle.net/orxkajw0/1/

Comment: You could pull that up by setting `grid-auto-flow: dense` but I'm not sure that really solves the core problem.

Comment: Or.. maybe it does?

Comment: I just tried, I don't see it working. You can play with the fiddle if you want :)

Comment: It fixes the gap above the last column in the first row, but other issues remain.

Comment: At least the wrapper works: https://jsfiddle.net/orxkajw0/2/ (I first tried with flex + grid, now it is grid + grid to force the second row to have the same height as the first row)